# Python read file script error

Tags: iso-8859-1

What's wrong with this python script:

```
RoomNumber = input("Enter the room number:")

text_file = open('roombookings.txt', 'r')
for line in text_file:
    (s['Date'], s['Room'], s['Course'], s['Stage']) = line.split(";")
    if RoomNumder == (s['Room']):
        print("Date: " + s['Date'])
        print("Room: " + s['Room'])
        print("Course: " + s['Course'])
        print("Stage: " + s['Stage'])
        text_file.close()

input("\n\nPress enter key to exit.")
```

I'm trying to get the date, course and stage as output on entering the room number, but something's wrong. When I run the script at

> "(s['Date'], s['Room'], s['Course'], s['Stage']) = line.split(";")"

I get a 'value error: need more than 1 value to unpack'. I don't know what that means.

Comment: You shouldn't close your file after first match as you'll end up with I/O error (`for` loop will try to read next line on closed file). Also note `line` contains line break as a last character and you might like to `line.rstrip()` it off.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> (s['Date'], s['Room'], s['Course'], s['Stage']) = line.split(";")
> ```
>
> I get a 'value error: need more than 1 value to unpack' I don't know
>   what that means.

It means that it's trying to find four values, to assign to the four keys listed on the left, but that the array produced by `line.split(";")` only contains one. The line in question must not contain a semicolon; it might be empty.

Comment: Nitpicking: If it says it needs "more than 1 value", `split` returned only 1 substring (i.e. the line unmodified because there is no semicolon at all). Likely a blank line.

Comment: @delnan Oops, I misread that as "1 more value". Correcting now.

Answer (score 1):

The *unpack* related error is pretty common in python and it tells you, that it was impossible to perform all requested assignments, i.e.

```
a,      = 1, 2  # ValueError: 'too many values to unpack'
a, b, c = 1,    # ValueError: 'need more than 1 value to unpack'
a, b, c = 1, 2  # ValueError: 'need more than 2 values to unpack'
```

As Jeremy Banks said, it looks like one of your lines doesn't contain semicolon (so no splits has been performed and you have only one value on right side of assignment). You need some kind of input validation.

Comment: what kind of input validation?

Comment: @ tomasz - what kind of input validation?

Comment: Your code says that file is supposed to contain lines with 3 semicolons each, but your error says it's not true. You want to make sure each line is correct or at least ignore some lines. Are you sure you don't have empty lines in your file?